# How do I convert this list into a data frame where each row is a single entity

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have this data set running into the '00,000 of rows, only 3 is shown here for brevity.

```
listy<-    list(ABR = list(ABN = list(text = "11000000948", .attrs = c(status = "ACT", 
    ABNStatusFromDate = "19991101")), EntityType = list(EntityTypeInd = "PUB", 
        EntityTypeText = "Australian Public Company"), MainEntity = list(
        NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "QBE INSURANCE (INTERNATIONAL) LTD", 
            .attrs = c(type = "MN")), BusinessAddress = list(AddressDetails = list(
            State = "NSW", Postcode = "2000"))), ASICNumber = list(
        text = "000000948", .attrs = c(ASICNumberType = "undetermined")), 
        GST = c(status = "ACT", GSTStatusFromDate = "20000701"), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "QBE INSURANCE (INTERNATIONAL) LIMITED", 
            .attrs = c(type = "TRD"))), .attrs = c(recordLastUpdatedDate = "20180216", 
        replaced = "N")), ABR = list(ABN = list(text = "11000002568", 
        .attrs = c(status = "CAN", ABNStatusFromDate = "20190501"
        )), EntityType = list(EntityTypeInd = "PRV", EntityTypeText = "Australian Private Company"), 
        MainEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "TOOHEYS PTY LIMITED", 
            .attrs = c(type = "MN")), BusinessAddress = list(AddressDetails = list(
            State = "NSW", Postcode = "2141"))), ASICNumber = list(
            text = "000002568", .attrs = c(ASICNumberType = "undetermined")), 
        GST = c(status = "CAN", GSTStatusFromDate = "20190502"), 
        .attrs = c(recordLastUpdatedDate = "20190531", replaced = "N"
        )), ABR = list(ABN = list(text = "11000016722", .attrs = c(status = "ACT", 
    ABNStatusFromDate = "20000303")), EntityType = list(EntityTypeInd = "PUB", 
        EntityTypeText = "Australian Public Company"), MainEntity = list(
        NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "INSURANCE AUSTRALIA LIMITED", 
            .attrs = c(type = "MN")), BusinessAddress = list(AddressDetails = list(
            State = "NSW", Postcode = "2000"))), ASICNumber = list(
        text = "000016722", .attrs = c(ASICNumberType = "undetermined")), 
        GST = c(status = "ACT", GSTStatusFromDate = "20000701"), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "NRMA INSURANCE LTD", 
            .attrs = c(type = "TRD"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "NRMA INSURANCE LTD-WORKERS COMPENSATION", 
            .attrs = c(type = "OTN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "\"\"Wesfarmers Federation Insurance\"\"", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Aim Dealer Services", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Aim Insurance", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Airport Buddy", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Assureme", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Australian Union Assurance", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Bitsy Cover", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "BuddyCover", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "C G U Insurance", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "C G U Professional Risks Insurance", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "C G U Trade Credit Insurance", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "C G U Travel Insurance", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "CGU Advantage", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "CGU Cyber Defence", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "CGU Home Warranty Insurance", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "CGU Insurance", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "CGU Professional Risks Insurance", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "CGU SAFETY AND RISK SERVICES", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "CGU SELF INSURANCE SERVICES", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "CGU Trade Credit Insurance", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "CGU Travel Insurance", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "CGU Workers Compensation", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Dairypol", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Grain Farmers Crop Insurance Agency", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Grainpol", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "IAG Insurance", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "IAG Re Australia", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "IAL.com.au", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Insurance 4 That", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Insurance for That", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "InsureLite", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Kwikinsure", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Lioncare", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Lumley Connect", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Lumley General", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Lumley General Insurance", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Lumley Insurance", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Lumley Marine & Logistics", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Lumley Online", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Lumley Retail Warranty", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Lumley Special Vehicles", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Metrorider", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "mobility.ai.", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "MOTOR TRADE DIRECT", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Motorassist", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Mums & Company", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "My.Place@Lumley", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "NRMA HOME SECURITY", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "NRMA HOME SECURITY", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "NRMA HOME SECURITY", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "NRMA INSURANCE", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "NRMA INSURANCE", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "NRMA INSURANCE", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "NRMA INSURANCE", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "NRMA SECURITY", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "NRMA SECURITY", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "NRMA SECURITY", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "NZI Insurance", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Pacific Indemnity", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Poncho Insurance", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Pounce Pet Insurance", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Prestige Boat Insurance", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Prestige Car Insurance", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Prestige Home Insurance", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Quick Insure", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Safer Journeys", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "SGI Insurance", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "SGI.com.au", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "SGIC", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "SGIC HOME SECURITY", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "SGIC INSURANCE", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "SGIC SECURITY", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "SGIO", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "SGIO HOME SECURITY", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "SGIO INSURANCE", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "SGIO SECURITY", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Sharecover Enterprises", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Swann Insurance", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "THE BUZZ INSURANCE", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "THE BUZZ INSURANCE", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "THE BUZZ INSURANCE", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "THE BUZZ INSURANCE", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "The United Insurance Co", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "The United Insurance Company", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "VACC Insurance", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "VACC Rural Insurance", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Warrante-Link Warranty Solutions", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Warrantyassist", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "Wesfarmers Federation Insurance", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "WFI", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(NonIndividualNameText = "'WFI'", 
            .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), OtherEntity = list(NonIndividualName = list(
            NonIndividualNameText = "Yourinsurancegroup", .attrs = c(type = "BN"))), 
        .attrs = c(recordLastUpdatedDate = "20190612", replaced = "N"
        )))

xmldf <- data.table::rbindlist(listy, fill = TRUE)
```

I am trying to convert this into a data frame where each row maps into a list element. In this case there should be 3 (rows). It looks like the ABR$ABN$.attrs (and in some cases ABR$GST$.attrs) is forcing the data frame into 2 rows after running this function on the list data.table::rbindlist(list, fill = TRUE). See the picture for an [table showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3284.gif)example:

How can I "flatten"? the two rows into 1?

Edit1: Added a bit more code in the example to facilitate a simple cut paste and run in your R instance

Comment: I'm getting an error. You probably dropped a parenthesis somewhere. Maybe you can make a smaller sample and include what you're trying to get

Comment: @camille - tweaked the code so it can be cut and pasted. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
nlist <- lapply(listy,function(x) as.list(unlist(x)))
xmldf <- data.table::rbindlist(nlist, fill = TRUE)
```

The `unlist` will "flatten" the structure and `as.list` will allow it to be treated as a 1 row dataframe.

I got a `data.table` with 3 rows and 203 columns. First few columns look like this:

```
      ABN.text ABN..attrs.status ABN..attrs.ABNStatusFromDate EntityType.EntityTypeInd
1: 11000000948               ACT                     19991101                      PUB
2: 11000002568               CAN                     20190501                      PRV
3: 11000016722               ACT                     20000303                      PUB
```